# Php don't add url parameter that already exisits

Tags: php, url

In php I'm adding an extra URL segment `?sort` to sort posts by ascending or descending.

```
    <?php
    //get current URL
    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    //filter URL and create sorting links
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
    { ?>         
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>?sort=asc">Small</a>
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>?sort=desc">Large</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

The problem: every time I click a link the url segment repeats in the URL.

Example: `http://mysite.com/another_segment/?sort=asc?sort=asc?sort=asc`

To disallow repetition, how I replace the URL segment whenever I click one of the two sorting link? I don't need to separate parameters with `&` symbols. I'm expecting just one delimiter. I'm using it in a pagination script so the parameter needs to stay in the URL when I browse pages.

I'm trying to avoid javascript as well

Comment: That's probably because of what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains, ie, `/another_segment/?sort=asc`. This is illustrative: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/_SERVER_PHP.htm

Comment: @JaredFarrish - That would explain it if it was repeating twice. But 3 times?

Comment: @Paul - Sure, why not? Try my demo: http://jfcoder.com/test/url.php

Comment: @JaredFarrish it repeats 3 times when clicked 3 times

Comment: CyberJunkie - I'm not sure what your comment means, but that's what I was after to replicate your problem (I think...?). Try it again (http://jfcoder.com/test/url.php), I added a source view. It's pretty much your code.

Comment: @JaredFarrish sorry i misunderstood, Yes your code simulates exactly what happens thanks

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Sorry, my mistake. I misunderstood what CyberJunkie was asking for

Comment: There's a much better and more reliable solution using `parse_url`,  `parse_str` and `http_build_query`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following function to remove the  "sort" key in the existing URL and then append.

```
function remove_querystring_var($url, $key) { 
  $url = preg_replace('/(.*)(?|&)' . $key . '=[^&]+?(&)(.*)/i', '$1$2$4', $url . '&'); 
  $url = substr($url, 0, -1); 
  return $url; 
}
```

Your code should modify this way

```
   <?php
    //get current URL
    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     $url = remove_querystring_var($url, "sort");
    //filter URL and create sorting links
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
    { ?>         
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>?sort=asc">Small</a>
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>?sort=desc">Large</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the function and code but for some reason it don't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Strip the querystring from `$url` and rebuild `$_GET` with `&` appended.

```
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip the query string from URL
list($url,) = explode('?', $url);

// Remove 'sort' from querystring if exist
if (isset($_GET['sort']))
    unset($_GET['sort']);

// Rebuild query string, append with '&'
$url .= '?'. http_build_query($_GET).(count($_GET) ? '&' : '');

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{ ?>         
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>sort=asc">Small</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>sort=desc">Large</a>
<?php } ?>
```

This way you can have URLs with querystring parameters but only one `sort=asc|desc`:

```
http://example.com/some/path?page=1&last=1500&sort=asc
http://example.com/some/path?page=1&last=1500&sort=desc
```

Answer (score 1):

To strip the query string from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, use `$URI = strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?", true);`.

[Reference: php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php);

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$get_asc = $get_desc = $_GET;
$get_asc['sort'] = 'asc';
$get_desc['sort'] = 'desc';

if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { ?> 
    <a href="<?php echo $url . '?' . http_build_query($get_asc); ?>">Small</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $url . '?' . http_build_query($get_desc); ?>">Large</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead of `REQUEST_URI`.